# Pearson correlation in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I have two different parameters raster data, Which are temperature (X) and precipitation (Y). For temperature (X) and precipitation (Y), each parameters have 12 data files (Tiff format).

I want to perform Pearson's correlation coefficient analysis between two parameters and want output as a raster format. I have tried to do it in Arc GIS but I think in ArcGIS not providing such type computing facility.

So I am looking for a solution in an R based software package. I am new in R.

I keep my rasters in two different file, Below I have attached my folder situation which is shown below. How can i assign here path for the two different raster parameters.

[image]

Comment: I would take pause on the statistical support of this analysis. Other than addressing general curiosity, the Pearson's correlation is not  well supported, statistically, for any empirical conclusions. The data are both spatially and serially autocorrelated and not necessarily multivariate normal. An alternative would be the nonparametric Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (ks.test function), which compares the equivalence of two distributions. You could make a raster of the p-values, indicating rejection of the null at a given significance. For pair-wise raster correlations look at spatialEco::hmwCorr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll expose the solution with two random datasets, one for temperature and one for precipitation:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster()

t1 <- setValues(r , rnorm(n=64800,mean=16,sd=1))
t2 <- setValues(r , rnorm(n=64800,mean=18,sd=1))
t3 <- setValues(r , rnorm(n=64800,mean=20,sd=1))
t4 <- setValues(r , rnorm(n=64800,mean=22,sd=1))
t5 <- setValues(r , rnorm(n=64800,mean=24,sd=1))
t6 <- setValues(r , rnorm(n=64800,mean=26,sd=1))

p1 <- setValues(r , runif(64800,0,70))
p2 <- setValues(r , runif(64800,0,60))
p3 <- setValues(r , runif(64800,0,50))
p4 <- setValues(r , runif(64800,0,40))
p5 <- setValues(r , runif(64800,0,30))
p6 <- setValues(r , runif(64800,0,20))

temp <- stack(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6)
pp <- stack(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6)
```

Extract values for each dataset:

```
tempValues<- values(temp)
ppValues <- values(pp)
```

Create a vector to store results and make a loop for correlation computation:

```
corValues <- vector(mode = 'numeric')

for(i in 1:dim(tempValues)[1]){
  corValues[i] <- cor(x = tempValues[i,], y = ppValues[i,], method = 'pearson')
}
```

Create a new raster with correlation results:

```
correlationRaster <- setValues(r, values = corValues)

plot(correlationRaster)
```

[image: plot]

There is a unique consideration for this answer: both datasets must have the same extent, cell size and CRS.

---

Edit:

The example was to create 6 different layers and stack them to create a multi-layer raster. In your case, just simply load each multi-layer raster with 'stack' function:

```
npp <- stack('D:/Test_Corr/MODIS_NPP/r001_NPP.tif')

wue <- stack('D:/Test_Corr/MODIS_WUE/r001_WUE.tif')

nppValues<- values(npp)
wueValues <- values(wue)

corValues <- vector(mode = 'numeric')

for(i in 1:dim(nppValues)[1]){
  corValues[i] <- cor(x = nppValues[i,], y = wueValues[i,], method = 'pearson')
}

correlationRaster <- setValues(r, values = corValues)
```

If datasets doesn't have the same extent, crop one of them (the bigger one) before with:

```
npp <- crop(npp,wue)

#or

wue <- crop(wue,npp)
```

Comment: Thanks, i have run the code. It yields the same output which you attached. As I updated my query along with my raster files location, now how to link my raster file path with your command line `t1 <- setValues(r , rnorm(n=64800,mean=16,sd=1))`  ........... t12 and `p1 <- setValues(r , runif(64800,0,70))` till p12.

Comment: This seems helpful to my problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277575/how-to-do-spatial-correlation-between-two-sets-of-rasters-in-r?noredirect=1#comment442586_277575

Though, I am not sure how to run the correlation if I have a series of rasters.

Comment: @user2543 is exactly what I have done here. Compare 6 rasters with other 6 rasters and compute a correlation value per pixel

Comment: Thanks. In the link I provided, I have list.files. How can I loop them from 1..200.  do I stack them also? How do i do that in code? In your example, you enumated each file. It would be difficult to do that 200 times.

Comment: @aldo_tapia: I used your code and there was an error that shows: In corValues[i] <- cor(x = redtemp[i, ], y = bluetemp[i,  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. My edited code can be found here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277575/how-to-do-spatial-correlation-between-two-sets-of-rasters-in-r?noredirect=1#comment442586_277575

Comment: @user2543 in the data provided, you have a different number of layers for red and nir. That could be the error

Comment: @aldo_tapia: I have edited the uploaded files to BLUE001...BLUE010.tif and RED001...RED010.tif. There was an error in the file sharing site.

Comment: @user2543 I used your files and the code works. I used the same code (also the code in your question): https://imgur.com/a/NUu1J

Comment: @aldo_tapia. Thank you. Can you show me how you did the loop? Did you enumerate the BLUE001 to BLUE010.tif? And RED001 to RED010.tif? I have 200 files for each band. What do I input in the rnorm, mean? If you would be so kind, can you upload the code you used.

Comment: I use the same code. If you have problems with the raster name, use the same workaround of this answer to you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276422/looping-for-ndvi-in-different-file-paths-using-r/276464#276464

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6rvldjcnxqsys3/Capture.PNG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l00yp6wxijbzvfu/Capture2.PNG?dl=0

These are codes and errors I get.

Comment: I used `r <- raster()` to create an empty raster for examples. You need to use `correlationRaster <- setValues(temp[[1]],values = corValues)`. Read carefully the error message, it says everything you need to solve this issue

Comment: Thank you! I restarted my PC and it worked. I don't know why but it did

Comment: Hi, in your example, you specified the path and FIRST FILE only. 

    I used this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yksye2dbio3pddh/GISSE.PNG?dl=0

Do  you think it's the same? When I tried using what you coded, there is no correlationRaster.

Comment: Also, is there a way I can flag significant Pearson's R in the output raster?

Comment: @user2543 1) you are listing files with a regular expression to match for your needs. Correlation raster doesn't match with 'BLUE*.*.tif' or 'RED*.*.tif'. 2) To flag, just create a logic test like `correlationRaster >= 0.8 | correlationRaster <= -0.8`, you can use `mask()` to exclude values outside this test